# Serialize XML with Namespace

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

I want to generate the below XML request. When I use the XML to C# tool to generate classes for this request and then serialize to call webservice, my generated request doesn't have `p:` in root, hence my request fails. Can anyone help please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ">
  <GetQuote>
    <Request>
      <ServiceHeader>
        <MessageTime>2002-08-20T11:28:56.000-08:00</MessageTime>
        <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678901</MessageReference>
        <SiteID>DDDDD</SiteID>
        <Password>XXXX</Password>
      </ServiceHeader>
    </Request>
  </GetQuote>
</p:DCTRequest>
```

This is my code to serialize the classes:

```
public static string Serialize(object dataToSerialize) 
{ 
    if (dataToSerialize == null) return null; 
    using (Utf8StringWriter stringwriter = new Utf8StringWriter()) 
    { 
        XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();  
        ns.Add("p", "DCTRequest"); 
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType()); 
        serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize); 
        return stringwriter.ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Show how do you do serialization.

Comment: public static string Serialize(object dataToSerialize)
  {
   if (dataToSerialize == null) return null;

   using (Utf8StringWriter stringwriter = new Utf8StringWriter())
   {
               //XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
               // ns.Add("p", "DCTRequest");
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType());
    serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, dataToSerialize);
    return stringwriter.ToString();
   }
  }           //I Used this function for serialization

Comment: [Edit] the question. Move the code from the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you could achieve the desired result. I tested using the following class structure. Nothing too special about this, other than having the `SchemaLocation` property on the DCTRequest to make sure you get the `xsi:schemaLocation` in the final XML, and setting the outer namespace to "http://www.dhl.com" which will give it the `p` prefix later.

```
[XmlRoot(Namespace = "http://www.dhl.com")]
public class DCTRequest
{

    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "schemaLocation", Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance")]
    public string SchemaLocation { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(Namespace = "")]
    public GetQuote GetQuote { get; set; }
}

public class GetQuote
{
    public Request Request { get; set; }
}

public class Request
{
    public ServiceHeader ServiceHeader { get; set; }
}

public class ServiceHeader
{
    public DateTime MessageTime { get; set; }
    public string MessageReference { get; set; }
    public string SideID { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

I have adapted your serialization method as follows. Two things you have wrong here:

- You've passed an object/element name `DCTRequest` as the namespace. That's wrong, a namespace takes the form `http://www.mynamespace.com/whatever`. In your case, you have `xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com"`. The `p` is referred to as the namespace prefix. It is a short hand way of referencing the full namespace which is `http://www.dhl.com`.
- You don't pass the instance of the `XmlSerializerNamespaces` in the call to `serializer.Serialize`, so it's not used and doesn't do anything.

Here is a fixed version:

```
public static string Serialize(object dataToSerialize)
{
    if (dataToSerialize == null) return null;
    using (StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
        namespaces.Add("p", "http://www.dhl.com");
        namespaces.Add("p1", "http://www.dhl.com/datatypes");
        namespaces.Add("p2", "http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes");
        namespaces.Add("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(dataToSerialize.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, dataToSerialize, namespaces);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }        
}
```

If you put it together and call like this:

```
var dctRequest = new DCTRequest()
{
    SchemaLocation = "http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ",
    GetQuote = new GetQuote()
    {
        Request = new Request()
        {
            ServiceHeader = new ServiceHeader()
            {
                MessageTime = DateTime.Now,
                MessageReference = "1234567890123456789012345678901",
                SideID = "DDDDD",
                Password = "XXXX"
            }
        }
    }
};

var xml = Serialize(dctRequest);
```

Then you will get your desired XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<p:DCTRequest xmlns:p2="http://www.dhl.com/DCTRequestdatatypes" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p1="http://www.dhl.com/datatypes" xmlns:p="http://www.dhl.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com DCT-req.xsd ">
  <GetQuote>
    <Request>
      <ServiceHeader>
        <MessageTime>2018-12-22T10:09:06.6530604+00:00</MessageTime>
        <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678901</MessageReference>
        <SideID>DDDDD</SideID>
        <Password>XXXX</Password>
      </ServiceHeader>
    </Request>
  </GetQuote>
</p:DCTRequest>
```